# Start Activity after getting GPS Location

Tags: android, gps, android-activity

How can I start another activity after I have retrieved the location of the phone through GPS? I have a splash screen that I would like to dismiss after the phone has gotten the location of the phone. So I have the following code:

```
private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locManager.removeUpdates(this);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};
```

After the location is retrieved I remove the updates and want to start the next activity. Suggestions?

Comment: I have one...tell us the problem you are having when running the code, including any and all error messages/logcat output

Comment: ADT is giving me a compiler error. When I try to create a new intent.

Comment: I don't have access to the view or context inside that method.

Comment: Try replacing 'this' with `YourActivityName.this`

Comment: I did, and I get the same error

Comment: What line is giving you that error?

Comment: The line where I am setting the intent and calling startActivity

Comment: I think I see your problem. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startActivity()` needs a `context`. If this is inside of an `Activity` then try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
YourActivityName.this.startActivity(intent);
```

If it is a separate class then you need to pass `context` to the class and use that with `startActivity()`

Comment: @CodeMagick you need to also YourActivity.this in new Intent

Comment: @HoanNguyen you're right, thanks, I have edited my answer. I mentioned that in a comment on the OP and Walter said he tried that so I just forgot to add it here. Thanks for the catch

Comment: Yes I noticed that you said that in the comment and know you forgot.

Comment: This has taken care of my compiler error, but I'll have to install it on my device to make sure that everything works smoothly.